# How trigger console.log every time mui tooltip is displayed?

Tags: material-ui

return <MUITooltip onOpen={console.log("ping")}> and useEffects only trigger on page refresh, I want them to trigger when I'm hovering over the parent element. I'm using material-ui 4. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm stupid. The correct syntax is:
<MUITooltip onOpen={() => console.log("ping")}>